# How to load the same last component class in react native using react navigation?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My application scenario is like, let say you have three components:

```
class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Component One</Text>
        <Button
        title='Go To Component Two' 
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('two')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Component Two</Text>
        <Button
        title='Go To Component Three' 
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('three')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentThree extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Component Three</Text>
        <Button
        title='Go To Component One'
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('one')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({one: ComponentOne,two: ComponentTwo,three: ComponentThree});
```

Now when I load the app the `ComponentOne` will be loaded, inside the `ComponentOne` when I click on the button `Go To Component Two` it will navigate me to the `ComponentTwo`, inside `ComponentTwo` when I click on the button  `Go To Component Three` it will navigate me to the `ComponentThree` and so on. Now let say I am in `ComponentTwo` and on the same time I close the application in the phone and I open the app switcher and clean all the running apps and load the same app again, so, it will be again loaded with `ComponentOne`.

My question is how to program the `react navigation` to continue from the same component where last time I left, even after cleaning the app from a background (cleaning all apps in app switcher)?

Is there any builtin way in `react navigation` to do this? Can anyone tell? Examples will be more appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Navigators have `onNavigationStateChange` where you can handle the navigation state changing. Example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  ComponentOne: {
    screen: ComponentOne,
  },
  ComponentTwo: {
    screen: ComponentTwo,
  },
  ComponentThree: {
    screen: ComponentThree,
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'ComponentOne',
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.navigator = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      // Retrieve the last route
      const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('lastNavigationRoute').then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          this.navigator.current.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: result,
          }));
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // handle the error
    }
  }

  handleStateChange = (previousState, nextState) => {
    // Here we get the Navigate action type only
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'dummyRoute' });

    if (action.type === navigateAction.type) {
      try {
        // Saving the last route
        AsyncStorage.setItem('lastNavigationRoute', nextState.routeName);
      } catch (e) {
        // handle the error
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    // You could also set a state with loader to handle loading from AsyncStorage
    return (
      <Navigator onNavigationStateChange={this.handleStateChange} ref={this.navigator} />
    );
  }
}
```

How it works:

- On every navigation state changing you also save the last `routeName`
  from `Navigate` action
- When component did mount, you check for saved
  route in `AsyncStorage`
- If there is a route, you dispatch the navigate action (it's possible to implement replace action as well)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I am doing the same thing but I was letting know maybe there is some standard way in **react navigation** we can do it without using the storage.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think that there is a solution directly using react-navigation. 
What i think you could do is to save a value of the current screen to the storage of the phone and then use this value on app start to detect which screen to show